# Rhino Mock AAA expectation inside of expectation

Tags: rhino-mocks, arrange-act-assert

Is it possible to mock the following situation, using Rhino Mock AAA syntax:

```
// Interface
interface IFoo
{
    void ExecuteFoo( Expression<Action> action );
    void Increment(out int value); // value++
}

// Situation to mock:
var foo = new Foo();
int value = 7;
foo.ExecuteFoo( () => foo.Increment( out value ) );    

// and here is mock that needs to be remade:
fooMock.Expect( f => f.ExecuteFoo( Arg<Expression<Action>>.Is.NotNull ));
fooMock.ExecuteFoo( () => foo.Increment( out value ) );
```

But instead of .Is.NotNull constraint somehow I need to pass this expectation:

```
fooMock.Expect(f => f.Increment(out Arg<int>.Out(8).Dummy));
```

I know it may seem a little bit odd, but let's say that ExecuteFoo is crucial and it has to be done like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really set expectations on lambdas because of the way they are handled by the compiler.  See: http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/archive/2010/06/18/rhino-mocks-lambdas-and-expectations.aspx